# Can we simulate windows date and time to identify by php project?

Tags: php, date, future

I have a php project wherein there is option to select date for sending notifications on predefined interval starting from the selected date.
for eg. send notification to users on 5th of every month starting today.

My php script checks the system's/server's current date and time and run the scheduler accordingly to send the notifications.

I can test this by changing system's date and time but my question is i want to test whether the notifications are out on 5th date of every month without changing the system date and time.
I can't change the system's date and time due to some reasons. So can we simulate the future dates and let php identify that date as current date. If this is possible, please let me know how to achieve it.

Edit : one more thing i would like to add. I want to test this thing as a tester so i can't change the existing code.

Thanks & Regards

Zeeshan Shaikh

Comment: You can encapsulate the logic of obtaining of current time into a separate class and mock it.

Answer (score 0):

YOu can try http://php.net/manual/en/function.override-function.php to override time() function (or what you use to get the date and time).